# How do I set the the app name of the WM_CLASS string of a tkinter window?

Tags: python, ubuntu, tkinter

### Introduction

In order to group several instances of a given application under one icon in the desktop launcher (I am using Ubuntu 17.04) they must have the same appName property of the WM_CLASS string. For example, if I run `emacs` twice:

```
$ emacs &
$ emacs &
```

Both instances will show up under the Emacs icon in the desktop launchbar. The reason is that both instances have the same WM_CLASS string. We can check this string using

```
$ xprop WM_CLASS
```

and then click on the Emacs window. It then shows:

```
WM_CLASS(STRING) = "emacs", "Emacs"
```

Here "emacs" is the resource (appName), and "Emacs" is the className,
see [xdotool: what are “class” and “classname” for a window?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1060170/156688) for more information.

## Question

Consider this program (`my-tkapp.py`):

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk(className='myTkApp')
label = tk.Label(root, text="Hello World")
label.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

If I run this program twice:

```
$ my-tkapp.py &
$ my-tkapp.py &
```

and then run `xprop` to check the `WM_CLASS` property of both windows,
the first window gives:

```
WM_CLASS(STRING) = "myTkApp", "Mytkapp"
```

whereas the second gives:

```
WM_CLASS(STRING) = "myTkApp #2", "Mytkapp"
```

Note that `tkinter` has added a `#2` suffix to the app name property. This is not desired. It makes the window manager group the two windows under separate icons in the desktop launch bar.

How can I keep the same appName property of the WM_CLASS string for different instances of my application?

### See also

[How to add launcher icon for python script?](https://askubuntu.com/q/929536/156688)

Comment: Did you find a solution about this issue ? Please share it !!!

Comment: @DimitrisDimitriadis This is how far I have gotten: https://bugs.python.org/issue30791 . I haven't had time to go into the Python and Tcl sources yet to track this bug down..

Answer (score 1):

This is tkinters behavior by default. The className must be unique in order to work with [tkinter.send](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/send.html) and is documented as [appname](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/tk.html#M5).

> If newName is not specified, this command returns the name of the
> application (**the name that may be used in send commands to communicate
> with the application**). If newName is specified, then the name of the
> application is changed to newName. **If the given name is already in
> use, then a suffix of the form “ #2” or “ #3” is appended in order to
> make the name unique.** The command's result is the name actually
> chosen. newName should not start with a capital letter. This will
> interfere with option processing, since names starting with capitals
> are assumed to be classes; as a result, Tk may not be able to find
> some options for the application. If sends have been disabled by
> deleting the send command, this command will reenable them and
> recreate the send command.

Use [wm_group](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/wm.html#M44) instead. Also see this [Q&A for dialog windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72251396/13629335)

Answer (score -1):

While the first `string` does add the suffix, if you use the second `string` the `"Mytkapp"` in your configuration, it will apply to all versions of the app that are running.

Comment: This did not work for me. See [How to add launcher icon for python script?](https://askubuntu.com/q/929536/156688) for details